# Convolution by multiplying list of numbers in memory, so an inverse convolution algorithm?

Tags: c#, math, convolution, deconvolution

While "convolutions are multiplications in the frequency domain", they also seem also to be multiplications much more literally. For example if I adjoin numbers adjacently in memory into a sort of list:

```
5:  (byte) 00000101
22: (byte) 00010110
7:  (byte) 00000111
8:  (byte) 00001000

Becomes:

(Int32) 00000101000101100000011100001000
```

Then multiply this resulting list/number by another such list, the result is a convolution of one list with the other. The following C# program demonstrates this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        var a = combine_to_Int64(A);
        var B = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        var b = combine_to_Int64(B);
        var c = a * b;
        var C = separate_to_8_byte(c);
        var d = deconvolution(c, b); // not correct
        var D = separate_to_8_byte(d);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "The convolution of (" + to_string(A) + ") with ("
            + to_string(B) + ") is: (" + to_string(C) + ")");
        Console.WriteLine(
            "The deconvolution of (" + to_string(C) + ") with ("
            + to_string(B) + ") is: (" + to_string(D) + ")");
    }

    public static Int64 convolution(Int64 a, Int64 b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    private static Int64 combine_to_Int64(byte[] n)
    {
        if (n.Length == 4)
            return n[0] + 65536 * n[1] + 4294967296 * n[2] +
                281474976710656 * n[3];
        else if (n.Length == 8)
            return n[0] + 256 * n[1] + 65536 * n[2] + 16777216 * n[3] +
                4294967296 * n[4] + 1099511627776 * n[5] +
                281474976710656 * n[6] + 72057594037927936 * n[7];
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    private static Int16[] separate_to_4_Int16(Int64 a)
    {
        return new []{(Int16) a, (Int16) (a >> 0x10),
            (Int16) (a >> 0x20), (Int16) (a >> 0x30)};
    }

    private static byte[] separate_to_8_byte(Int64 a)
    {
        return new []{(byte) a, (byte) (a >> 8), (byte) (a >> 0x10),
            (byte) (a >> 0x18), (byte) (a >> 0x20), (byte) (a >> 0x28),
            (byte) (a >> 0x30), (byte) (a >> 0x38)};
    }

    public static string to_string(byte[] values)
    {
        string s = "";
        foreach (var val in values)
            s += (s == "" ? "" : " ") + val;
        return s;
    }

    public static string to_string(Int16[] values)
    {
        string s = "";
        foreach (var val in values)
            s += (s == "" ? "" : " ") + val;
        return s;
    }

    // ---

    public static Int64 deconvolution(Int64 a, Int64 b)
    {
        var large = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(
            "1000000000000000000000000000000");
        return (Int64)(((
            (new System.Numerics.BigInteger(a) * large)
            / new System.Numerics.BigInteger(b))
            * 72057594037927936) / large);
    }
}
```

Try this code at: [rextester.com/YPKFA14408](http://rextester.com/YPKFA14408)

The output is:

```
The convolution of (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) with (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) is: (1 4 10 20 35 56 84 120)

The deconvolution of (1 4 10 20 35 56 84 120) with (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) is: (219 251 194 172 10 94 253 14)
```

A demonstration that the first line of the output is correct can be found here: https://oeis.org/A000292

> "Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences" … "Tetrahedral (or triangular pyramidal) numbers" … "the convolution of the natural numbers with themselves. - Felix Goldberg"

---

Q: What is wrong with the deconvolution function in the code provided, or with my understanding of what the result should be?

Comment: Sorry for such a maths heavy post, this perhaps fits somewhere between maths.SE and SO. I think that the posts contains programming concepts that seem more appropriate communicated as code than with formula, such as the core approach of multiplying bytes of memory as a single number.

Comment: Why is your deconvolution function multiplying the return result by 2^56?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: reverse time shift.  He's treating positional number notation as a shorthand for the z-transform, where 256 = (1 time unit of delay).  Therefore shift by 56 is the same as 7 units time delay.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's 64bit - 8bit. The amount I thought I might need to get every byte filled, without any such scaling only the first value in the sequence is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is carries.

Treat the inputs as polynomials...

```
00000101 becomes x^2 + x^0
00000111 becomes x^2 + x^1 + x^0
```

Polynomial multiplication and convolution are exactly the same operation (let `x` be `z`<sup>-1</sup>, the z-transform primitive for a delay... now multiplication is taking place in the transform domain after all)

But arithmetic multiplication is not the same as polynomial multiplication, because of carries.  The result of

```
(x^1 + x^0) * (x^1 + x^0)
```

is

```
x^2 + 2 x^1 + x^0
```

and indeed the convolution

```
conv([1 1], [1 1]) = [1 2 1]
```

but although

```
0011 * 0011
```

is similarly

```
0100 + 2 * 0010 + 0001
```

in arithmetic, `2 * 0010` becomes `0100`, and the final result of

```
1001
```

is totally different from convolution (polynomial multiplication), because of the carrying that took place.

The arithmetic result only holds when `x = 2`... but in convolution `x` **must** be the time delay operator.

The same effect occurs if you are working with groups of 8 bits each representing the amplitude of one time sample.  Arithmetic within a group is ok, but as soon as you have a carry across a group boundary, the equivalence between convolution and multiplication is lost.

Comment: This explains why it's worked correctly with a number of convolution examples I've given it by using multiplication but won't work with convolution ones using division?

Comment: @alan2here: Division is happy to treat remainder at any step as extra magnitude in the neighboring position.  You need to do polynomial division, where the borrows don't cross coefficients.  But you can easily cause the multiplication examples to break down, by arranging for any of the coefficients in the result to overflow an 8-bit byte.

Comment: @alan2here: For one thing, deconvolution will frequently produce negatives.  Your scheme doesn't even have an encoding to represent negative values in the sequence.

Comment: Surprisingly (having found discovering this whole thing full of enormous surprises) you can use negative values in the elements of the list, and it works. For example, try having some negative, and some positive elements, then multiplying by a negative or positive value. You can also use unsigned numeric types instead of signed ones, and that works as expected too.

Comment: @alan2here: It's still going to work only as long as carries agree with sign-extension.  As soon as you have overflow in any position, it'll corrupt the one next to it.

Comment: Hmm, carrying too many places is a problem with multiplying too, I found (byte) and certainly Int16 elements easily large enough so that wasn't a problem though. With division it seems like perhaps that's always a problem. Maybe I must write code that manually implements the division such that the bits of elements aren't carried one to the other.

Comment: @alan2here: I think it'll be easier to understand if you do an exercise.  Do long division by hand of 130 / 11 and 103 / 11.  Then (x^2 + 3x) / (x + 1) and (x^2 + 3) / (x + 1).  Notice how the steps of long division and polynomial division diverge when polynomial division starts getting negative residues.